# Consulta Decode vs Case

Tags: sql, query, oracle, funções, desempenho

Temos duas formas de trabalhar com condição dentro de consultas em `Oracle SQL`, são elas o `Case` e o `Decode`, os dois tem a mesma função. Permitir de forma dinâmica e pratica como obter um retorno de uma coluna com base em uma condição.

Qual a diferença? qual é o melhor? e Porque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `decode` funciona como um `if` de algumas linguagens condição resultado

EXEMPLO

```
SELECT DECODE(TIPO_PESSOA,'J','JURIDICA','F','FISICA','DESCONHECIDO')
FROM CLIENTES
```

O *case* permite "regras" mais complexas

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN SALDO = 0 THEN  'BOM'
             WHEN SALDO BETWEEN 1 AND 800 THEN 'MEDIO'
             ELSE 'RUIM' END) TIPO_PAGADOR
FROM CLIENTES
```

consulte a documentação para mais detalhes.